# Handle error sending DM to users in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to for example send direct messages to users from an array. Discord doesn't allow me to send messages for some users, and I want to handle the error and continue sending messages. But I get errors and the bot is getting stop every time. Can I use some help?

```js
for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfUsersIDs.length; i++) {
    const element = arrayOfUsersIDs[i]
    const user = client.users.cache.get(element)
    try {
        user.send('My Message')
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```html
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Thetr\Desktop\tour\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Thetr\Desktop\tour\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/861307827499040778/messages',
  code: 50007,
  httpStatus: 403
}
```

Comment: What is happening when you run it like it is right now, with the try/catch?

Comment: @Alex Collette bot crashs

Comment: Please provide the error that it is giving, It is extremely hard to debug without context!

Comment: @Alex Collette edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using async function:

```js
async function sendDM (user, messageContent) {
  try {
    await user.send(messageContent)
    return true
  }
  catch (error) {
    return false
  }
}

// In my command

for (const element of arrayOfUsersIDs) {
  const user = client.users.cache.get(element)
  sendDM(user, 'My Message').then(result => {
    console.log(result) // true or false
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it failing to send is an asynchronous error. You must add `await` so it can handle the error.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfUsersIDs.length; i++) {
    const element = arrayOfUsersIDs[i]
    const user = client.users.cache.get(element)
(async () => {
    try {

       await user.send('My Message')
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

})
}
```

Also, since it *is* a promise, you can handle it with `.catch()`.

```js
user.send('My Message').catch(console.log);
```

Comment: Also, you can do a `for…of` loop to iterate through an array. Just something else to make it easier. `for(const element of arrayOfUsersIDs) {}` and element will be a user ID

Comment: I get this error with this code: client.users.cache.get(...) is not a function

Comment: Weird, if client wasn’t a real client, it would say cannot read property cache of undefined. That’s a mystery for now